# What does the ` sign means in BIP44?

Tags: wallets, addresses, hd-wallets

from the [BIP44 specification][1], the HD derivation path is defined as :

```
m / purpose' / coin_type' / account' / change / address_index
```

What does the `'` sign means in it?

Answer (score 0):

Apostrophe in the path means that its hardened derivation.
That means, that for a given wallet its **constant**.

Notice that the change and the address_index part is not marked as hardened. That's why you can generate multiple addresses for one account in e.g. bitcoin

Comment: And what will happen if one changes the hardened derivation parth --  `purpose` or  `coin_type` and then generates several addresses? As long as one remembers this custom path, there's no problem . Not?

Comment: Theoretically yes, but I can't state that for sure for all networks.
Lookup derivation path for ledger legacy

Comment: `I can't state that for sure for all networks` -- what do you mean? What issue could there arise? A network doesn't care about the derivation path, nor about its hardened parts either, does it? Only wallets do, because that use the hardcoded derivation paths